# Entity Framework Core not returning data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a new .NET Core application that is using Entity Framework Core. The query against the database returns no data.

The context is created like this:

```
private readonly ExtensionDataModel.DataSet1 _context = new ExtensionDataModel.DataSet1();
```

and the method using it is:

```
public ExtensionDetails GetExtensionDetails(string extension)
{
    var users = _context.Users;//.Where(x=>x.activeFlag==true);//.Where(x => x.workPhone.Contains("7029"));
                
    if (!users.Any())
    {
        return null;
    }

    var user = users.First();

    var detail = new ExtensionDetails()
            {
                Extension = user.workPhone,
                FirstName = user.firstName,
                LastName = user.lastName,
                Location = user.LocationsRow.LocationDesc
            };

    return detail;
}
```

I get no errors, and the users.Any returns false, even through there is data in the database.  If I expand the *users* object in the debugger, and look at the result set, the result set is empty.  Also, I have been unable to see the query that it is generating.

When I use SQL Server Profiler, it does not show any database activity.

When I go to the Entity Framework designer (clicking on DataSet1.xsd), I can right click on the users table and choose *Preview Data*, and it brings back the rows in the table.

I am using a separate SQL Server database server, and created the EF model by extracting it from the database.

My data model has two tables in it, and the user that I am using has only read access to those two tables.

Any help would be appreciated. I am new to .net core, but have been using EF for many years.
[image: Solution Explorer View]

Comment: I think the code in `ExtensionDataModel.DataSet1` class is more important to figure out your issue.

Comment: ExtensionDataModel.Dataset1 is entirely generated by Microsoft.

Comment: I don't think ef core supports xsd file. I normally write own DbContext class in code-first way.  You may use the `Graphical model editor`, which is in the comparison table in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/. this states that the method is `No support planned` in EF core.

Comment: I see that Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer (5.0.2) brings in Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 2.0.1.  My application did not recognize the SQL Client.  I had to bring in System.Data.SqlClient (4.8.1) for the program to compile.  Perhaps that is not compatible with Entity Framework,

Comment: Just for fun, I made my user an administrator in my database, in case there was a permissions problem.  Didn't work.